# Using Kafka KSQL to select all events of a topic from a specific partition with given offset

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Problem: I have a table in an external Database containing kafka events I polled from the Kafka Bus the last time. The table contains for all events the composite primary key PK(topic, partition, offset).

So I can easily for every topic and partition determine the latest event.

Now I would love to do an select like this:

```
SELECT event 
  FROM topic
 WHERE event.partition = partition0 AND event.offset > partition0.offset
    OR event.partition = partition1 AND event.offset > partition1.offset
...
```

And of course I would love that the statement returns immediately with all events currently in the queue, writing the result into an HDFS-File.

How would I do that with KSQL?

N.B.: Of course I would love to put all partitions with their corresponding offsets as pairs into an array and use that in the where clause ... that would be a premium solution.

Comment: Taking a step back…can you describe the pipeline/application that you're trying to build? i.e. without the implementation detail of database tables and offsets etc. From the sounds of it, you have data in Kafka, and you want to land it to HDFS? Are you doing other processing on it? From that I can give a more useful answer.

Comment: I am trying to get all events of a topic into a corresponding hive table, so we can do classic OLAP on the events. To have exactly once semantics without relying on external tools I would store (topic, partition, offset) per event in the the hive table, so that I know where to continue reading of the next batch of events from kafka ... even after a crash. The only processing during importing the kafka events would be a transformation from avro to a relational data model ... or if that is not possible, storing it just as it is.