# How to select/assign partition in KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I believe this is a related question:
[Using Kafka KSQL to select all events of a topic from a specific partition with given offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821517/using-kafka-ksql-to-select-all-events-of-a-topic-from-a-specific-partition-with)

How do you select/assign a partition via KSQL? I'm trying to prevent KSQL from reading from all partitions, as the necessary data only lives in one shard.

For example:

CLI v5.4.1, Server v5.4.1

```
SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';
CREATE STREAM SOURCE_STREAM (FIELD_1 BIGINT)
    WITH (
        VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO',
        KAFKA_TOPIC='source_topic',
        PARTITIONS=2,
        REPLICAS=1
    );
```

Insert some mock data which lives in partition 0 and partition 1 (not really assigned but for example)

```
INSERT INTO SOURCE_STREAM (FIELD_1) VALUES (123);  # say in partition 0
INSERT INTO SOURCE_STREAM (FIELD_1) VALUES (456);  # say in partition 1
```

With a consumer API one could do the following:

```
consumer.assign(TopicPartition(topic=source_topic, partition=0))
consumer.assign(TopicPartition(topic=source_topic, partition=1))
consumer.get()
```

However, with the current API I'm unsure how to "assign" a partition either at the client level or at the server property level. The below derivative stream would read from all partitions:

```
CREATE STREAM DERIVATIVE_STREAM AS 
    SELECT
        FIELD_1
    FROM SOURCE_STREAM
    EMIT CHANGES;

EXPLAIN CSAS_DERIVATIVE_STREAM_n;
```

(I know I can use a `WHERE` statement to filter the data but I want to explicitly read from partition 0|1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ksqlDB doesn't work this way. You use SQL to declare *what* you want, not *how* you want it.

As you said in your question, you can use `WHERE` to apply a predicate to your query, and can use `ROWKEY` to target the message key value.

I guess the parallel in the RDBMS world would be an execution plan hint for the cost-based optimiser.

If you want to log this as an enhancement request to ksqlDB please do so here: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new